# Bookmarks In Firefox 69.0.1

Tags: firefox

I have been using Internet Explorer for many years. I love it, but many sites are no longer accessible with it since the advent of Edge. I have downloaded Mozilla onto my Windows 10 computer, but when I bookmark a site, I can't find it outside Mozilla. Internet Explorer has always, and continues to, store bookmarks (Favorites) in a folder in Windows Explorer or File Explorer now. This was after shutting down Internet Explorer, I can go to the Favorites folder, or a shortcut of it on the desktop, select whatever favorites I want and then delete them, move them to an external device (USB, External Hard Drive, etc.) sort them by date, etc. I need to be able to do this in Mozilla, but I simply cannot find a definitive answer as to how to accomplish this. I would appreciate an explanation of how I can accomplish this. THANK YOU.

Comment: Firefox stores bookmarks inside a sqlite database and not as files, as described here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data Therefore I think what you want to accomplish is impossible without 3rd-party software.

Answer (score 2):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to display the Bookmarks *Library* dialog.

[image: *Firefox* Bookmarks Library]

- Select `Views` | `Show Columns >` to add the date `Added` and/or `Last Modified`.
- Click on a column header or use `Sort >` to select sort order.
- If you prefer to manually sort bookmarks, or arrange them into folders, just drag-and-drop them into the location you choose.
- Use `Import and Backup` to  export files as HTML, from which most modern browsers can import the data.
- The actual bookmarks within Firefox are stored as a [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database in 
  `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\profilename\places.sqlite` and backups are kept as compressed [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) files. These are standard data exchange formats, and are therefore interchangeable on all operating systems, including Linux and Mac, not as individual HTML shortcuts.

Comment: "The actual bookmarks within Firefox are stored as JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) files ..." I think this detail of your answer is wrong. Bookmarks are actually stored inside the `places.sqlite` database file within the profile folder. Only backups inside the `bookmarkbackups` folder are stored as JSON.

Comment: @dirdi, I stand corrected, as does the answer. Thanks!